# How can I directly load a xml string to a dataset? Instead of loading from a xml file?

Tags: xml, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset, load

I need a way to directly put an XML string to the Dataset. Instead of loading it from a file.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
            .option("rowTag", "book").load("books.xml");

df.show();
```

This works with simply calling the xml from a file. Is there any way to directly input an xml string to the Dataset? for example by using the string xmlString like shown below.

```
String xmlString = "<persons>
    <person id="1">
        <firstname>James</firstname>
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
        <middlename></middlename>
        <dob_year>1980</dob_year>
        <dob_month>1</dob_month>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <salary currency="Euro">10000</salary>
    </person>
</persons>";
```

The thing is I dont want to use files. I want to only use strings. I know there is a way to save the string to an xml file and then use the newly created xml file. but other than that is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the deprecated `xmlRdd` (which is the only solution, I can see now)

```
 public static void readFromString() {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Print Elements of RDD")
            .setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","2g");

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    String books = "<persons>\n" +
            "    <person id=\"1\">\n" +
            "        <firstname>James</firstname>\n" +
            "        <lastname>Smith</lastname>\n" +
            "        <middlename></middlename>\n" +
            "        <dob_year>1980</dob_year>\n" +
            "        <dob_month>1</dob_month>\n" +
            "        <gender>M</gender>\n" +
            "        <salary currency=\"Euro\">10000</salary>\n" +
            "    </person>\n" +
            "</persons>";

    List<String> booksList = Arrays.asList(books);

    RDD<String> booksRDD = sc.parallelize(booksList, 1).rdd();

    Dataset<Row> rowDataset = new XmlReader().withRowTag("person").xmlRdd(new SQLContext(sc), booksRDD);

    rowDataset.printSchema();

    rowDataset.select("person.*").show();

}
```

Result of `rowDataset.printSchema()`:

```
root
 |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dob_month: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dob_year: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- salary: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _currency: string (nullable = true)
```

Result of `rowDataset.select("person.*").show();`

```
+---+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+------------+
|_id|dob_month|dob_year|firstname|gender|lastname|middlename|      salary|
+---+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+------------+
|  1|        1|    1980|    James|     M|   Smith|          |[10000,Euro]|
+---+---------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+------------+
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah this worked! but is there a method to show() more than one row? like if I add another person there the ```rowDataset.select("person.*").show();``` throws an error..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640271/how-to-retrieve-a-value-from-struct-in-spark-java?answertab=votes#tab-top